# the Css is not read in the print code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I have tried this script but the style is not read properly while  printing can anyone help me figure out the problem?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnPrint").click(function () {
            var contents = $("#dvContents").html();
            var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
            frame1[0].name = "frame1";
            frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" });
            $("body").append(frame1);
            var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
            frameDoc.document.open();
            //Create a new HTML document.
            frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
            frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
            //Append the external CSS file.
            frameDoc.document.write('<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
            //frameDoc.document.write('<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
            //Append the DIV contents.
            frameDoc.document.write(contents);
            frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
            frameDoc.document.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.frames["frame1"].focus();
                window.frames["frame1"].print();
                frame1.remove();
            }, 500);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does your stylesheet include @media print?

Answer (score 0):

Issue may be with css file path.

Write it according to root path like this.....

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
```

Comment: the path is right it's the same as the one i used for the main page the problem is in the printing page i want to print a specific div with its UI